# Showing that $\frac{n}{(n!)^{1/n}}$ is monotonically increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

> I would like to show that the sequence
>   $$\frac{n}{(n!)^{1/n}}$$
>   is monotonically increasing.

I know that this sequence is non-negative, and that it converges to $e$, but I am unable to show that it is increasing.

Comment: Sterling approximation

Comment: Maybe you should show it for the $\ln$ of it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$a_n=\frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac 1n}}$$ then
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1) (n!)^{\frac{1}{n}} }{n((n+1)!)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}$$ Now, use Stirling approximation and show that
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\sim 1+\frac{1}{2 n^2}\log \left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{e}\right) \gt 1$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to derive a non-asymptotic proof that holds for any n?